# que otro metodo aplica en este caso, para hacer una busqueda

Tags: javascript

si find devuelve el primero del array, yo necesito hacer una busqueda de todos los elementos

```
  let itemProductos = Productos;
  arreglo.push(itemProductos)
 
  //for (let index = 0; index < arreglo.length; index++) {
  //let itemProducto =arreglo[index]= Productos.id === id;
  //console.log(itemProducto)

  let itemProducto =itemProductos.find(({id_a}) => id_a === id);
```

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter Saludos.

Comment: Saludos. Te sugiero explores Lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#find